# Is relative pitch trainable from scratch?

Tags: composition, self-learning, ear-training, relative-pitch

I know perfect pitch is not obtainable for adults (I'm over 20.) and I accepted it, okay. I even watched Rick Beato's video about it (youtube.com/watch?v=816VLQNdPMM) and read about it on the internet.

But I wouldn't think that every musician has relative / perfetch pitch since born or childhood.

Is there some way to obtain relative pitch good enough for example to play something from my head (maybe after hitting a reference key) or be a good music composer. (In my opinion, music like the ones in Solaris (2002) or dungeon synth songs like the one in Depressive Silence II or most synthwave songs or Blade Runner soundtrack (even songs from B.R. 2049)).

So, let's say I've got musical ideas, or compositions good enough to create songs like mentioned above or I just have some "sense" of composing, creating good melodies.

Can I train relative pitch what is good enough?

Also, I learn self-taught.

Comment: Actually, I obtained absolute pitch to some extent in adulthood. See my answer at https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16575/can-absolute-pitch-be-learned-or-acquired-by-anyone/90343#90343.

Comment: I see that ggcg's answer solved your problem but I don't know why. Did you actually try the advice in the answer then obtain some sort of absolute pitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend some software tools for this, Ear Master Pro, and Band in a Box.  EMP is designed solely for ear training and does what most music teachers do in lessons.  BB is more like a studio jam software but is has a cool video game like space invaders but to fire your gun you need to correctly identify an interval, scale, or chord.

The way music teacher introduce ear training is to have the student sit and not look at the instructor.  The instructor then plays some intervals and tells the student what they are, major 3rd, perfect fourth, etc.  Then they play them at random and the student has to recall the interval.  This evolves to more complex structures.  This is difficult to do yourself as you will know what you are playing if you play the intervals on a guitar or other instrument.  You need a partner for this to be effective.

Last but not least, sing.  If you take up singing you will tune your head better than any ear training exercises could.

Comment: I used to record intervals, etc., on minidisc and play them back on random. Each had a track number, so checking was easy.

Comment: @Tim, That works too.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. And pretty well essential for any serious player. One should be able to pitch any interval from a given note, hopefully vocally, and certainly on your instrument. Even if one doesn't understand what an interval is named, one ought to be able to hear an interval and play it, given a start note or key.

start with 1, 3 and 5, which are the notes making up a basic triad. We hear chords all the time, so it's an easy way to go - hear a 'root note', sing or play the 3 and the 5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact definitions but I think I read in another answer on this site that absolute pitch is the ability to sense the pitch of a note you hear with time and  perfect pitch is the ability to sense it instantly. When I was younger, I felt like I didn't have one absolute pitch one speck. I feel like slowly and graudually, by brain was getting closer to having that skill. I think that after watching a few episodes of the second season of "The Worst Witch" when I was 30, I would play the introduction music in my head at the right pitch before I started actually playing it and saw for myself that I indeed did get it right. The same happened for more episodes after that. Now, it often sometimes happens that I play music in my head at the correct pitch. It's not totally impossible for adults to obtain some extent of that ability. It just came all by itself naturally.